# Qt unixODBC FreeTDS

Tags: sql-server, linux, qt, odbc, unixodbc

I want to establish ODBC connection between Linux client and MSSQL Server.

I have installed unixODBC and FreeTDS, and tested isql and tsql both working fine and I am able to establish connection (this ensures proper connection establishment between client and server), but the problem is when I make Qt app, I am getting the following error:

> QSqlError(0, "QODBC3: Unable to connect", " [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified").

Which clearly tells that the settings files `odbc.ini`, `odbcinst.ini` and `freetds.conf` are not properly refered by Qt. Because when I remove these files same error message

> Data source not found

for isql and tsql is coming.

I created the link of all files in following locations

```
 /etc/
 /usr/local/etc/
 /etc/unixODBC/
```

but none of them were working, kindly guide me how to make Qt to refer the settings files or on which location the Qt refers for these files.